# Rendering react elements based on data from a db. Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {})

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

Relatively new to coding and particularly new to React. I'm working on building a job app and I want to conditionally render MUI chip react elements based on the database information returned from a useQuery pull in Apollo/client. Unfortunately, all I'm getting is some weird object instead of the react element I'm anticipating.

My code:

```
const handleSkillsChips = (skill) => {   
    
    switch(skill) {
      case 'Angular': 
      return <Angular />;

      case 'AWS': 
      return (<AWS />);

      case 'Bootstrap': 
      return(<Bootstrap />);
      
      case 'C++': 
      return(<Cplus />);
      
      case 'CSS': 
      return(<CSS />);

      case 'Express': 
      return(<Express />);

      case 'GitHub': 
      return (<Github />);
    
      case 'GraphQL': 
      return (<GraphQL />);
    
      case 'HTML': 
        return(<Html />);
     
      case 'JAVA': 
        return(<Java />);
  
      case 'JavaScript': 
        return(<JavaScript />);
    
      case 'MongoDB':
        return(<MongoDB />);
      
      case 'MySQL':
        return(<MySql />);
            
      case 'Node.js': 
      return(<NodeJS/>);
 
      case 'PHP': 
      return(<PHP />)
   
      case 'Python': 
      return (
      <Python />
      );
 
      case 'React.js': 
      return (<ReactJS />);

      case 'Rust': 
      return (<Rust />);

      case 'SQL': 
      return (<SQL />);
   
      case 'Vue.js': 
      return (<Vue />);
   
      case 'WordPress': 
      return (<Wordpress />);
    
      default: 
      return ( <Default />);

    }
  }
  

const Listing = () => {
    const {loading, data} = useQuery(GET_JOBS);
    const jobs = data?.jobs || [];
    const jobsSkills = jobs.map((job, i)=> jobs[i].skills)

    return (
      <div>
        { loading?
          <div>
            Loading job listings....
          </div>: 
          <div> 
            {jobs.map((job, i) => (      
            <Card key={i} className="col-8 mx-auto mb-4">
              <Card.Header>                
                {jobsSkills[i].map((skill) => handleSkillsChips(skill))}                
              </Card.Header>
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>{job.title}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">Tech Builders, Inc.</Card.Subtitle>
                <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">Atlanta, GA</Card.Subtitle>
                <Card.Text>"{job.description}"</Card.Text>
                <Button variant="primary" id="applyBtn" href={`//${job.link}`} target="_blank">Apply Here!</Button>{' '}
                <Button variant="primary" id="applyBtn" href={`//${job.link}`} target="_blank">Comment</Button>{' '}
              </Card.Body>
              <Card.Footer className="text-muted"> This job was posted on {job.createdAt}</Card.Footer>
            </Card>
              ))}
          </div>
        }   
      </div>
)}            
    

export default Listing;
```

JobSkills array looks like this:

```
0: ['JavaScript', 'Node.js']
1: ['CSS', 'Bootstrap']
2: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript']
3: ['Node.js']
4: ['Express.js']
5: ['React']
6: ['GraphQL']
7: ['Sequelize']
8: ['Handlebars.js']
9: ['MySQL']
10: ['MongoDB']
```

The error that keeps returning is

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}).
If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

How do I pull the skills out, and render them into their appropriate react element without triggering this odd object error?

Comment: I suspect your error is within the components you are returning from handleSkillsChips. We probably need to know what that is

Comment: When I directly inject them, they work just fine. However, as an example: `import "./skills.css"
import Chip from '@mui/material/Chip';
import {MDBIcon} from 'mdb-react-ui-kit';

const AWS = () => {
    return (
        <Chip className="chips" component="a" href="https://www.aws.training/" target="_blank" clickable      
          icon={
            <MDBIcon 
        fab
        icon="aws"/>
        }
        label="AWS"/>
    )
}

export default AWS;`

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I had to restructure the way the code functioned. Instead of writing a switch function to inject full components, I used 3 switch functions to input the particular information I needed to display the component I needed.

```
const getHref = (skill) => {
switch (skill.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'angular':
        return "https://angular.io/tutorial"

    case 'aws':
        return "https://www.aws.training/"
    default:
        return "https://www.coursera.org/courses?query=programming%20languages"
}
```

}

Additionally, added a switch case for the icon to be used and the label to be used in a MDBIcon component.

I then injected this into the JSX via:

```
                  {jobsSkills[i].map((skill)=> (
                <Chip className="chips" component="a" href={getHref(skill)} target="_blank" icon= {<MDBIcon fab icon={getIcon(skill)}/>} label={getLabel(skill)}/>
              ))}
```